# YFinance and Datatime Inputs

Tags: python, sql, datetime, format, yfinance

I am having trouble feeding in a date value to the YFinance python module. I keep getting the error that it cannot process the minutes/seconds values and just needs a regular date but I can't figure out how to feed that in.

Error is "   raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data "'2020-12-28'" does not match format '%Y-%m-%d"

The values print as if they are correct. Table yfinanceinputs holds the below values
Inputs
12/28/2020
12/31/2020
daily

```
SQL_Script2 = "SELECT * FROM yfinanceinputs"
pos = pd.io.sql.read_sql(SQL_Script2, cnxn)

inputs = pos.loc[:,'Inputs']

start_date = pd.to_datetime(inputs.values[0])
end_date = pd.to_datetime(inputs.values[1])
Day1 = pd.to_datetime(start_date).date()
End = pd.to_datetime(end_date).date()
Day1 = "'%s'" % Day1
End = "'%s'" % End

print(Day1)
print(End)

cnxn.close()

yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials(positions_held)
data = yahoo_financials.get_historical_price_data(Day1,End,'daily')
```

Comment: It appears that you are converting start_date and end_date to dates in Day1 and End, respectively, but still feed start_date and end_date into yahoo_financials

Comment: Sorry yes, I corrected my question. That was just so the rest of my code would run

Comment: What format does YFinance require the date to be in, string  or datetime?

Comment: yahoo finance datetimes are received as UTC

Comment: As a string or as a datetime object?

Comment: I believe datetime. This is from the source code:

    :param date_format_string: If `start_date` or `end_date` is not a :class:`DateTime` object,
        the object passed in (string) will be parsed to the format string. Default: `%Y-%m-%d`.

Comment: Try passing it as a string

Comment: So I formatted as such and received the below error:
start_date = inputs.values[0]
start_date = str(start_date)

    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '1/1/2020' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'